# extraer texto de la primera linea de un campo

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

tengo este código que de aquí sale una notificación por correo (esto aparece en el asunto del correo), pero en el campo de observaciones necesito extraerme solo la primera linea que se ponga, si dan enter y se pasa a la segunda linea, que tomé solo la primera linea que es la que se mandara por correo.

ejemplo si yo en el campo de observaciones pongo "esto es prueba" y doy un enter poniendo "sigue siendo prueba". quiero que tome la primera linea para mandarla por correo que vendría siendo "esto es prueba".

```
 If IdCliente = "2288" Then
       If Observaciones.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        Asunto &= "- OBSERVACIONES:" & Observaciones
       End If
     End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para extraer solo la primera línea de texto del campo de observaciones en VB.NET, puedes utilizar la función `Split()` para dividir el texto en líneas y luego acceder a la primera línea utilizando el índice 0

```
If IdCliente = "2288" Then
    If Observaciones.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        Dim lineas As String() = Observaciones.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        Dim primeraLinea As String = lineas(0).Trim()
        Asunto &= "- OBSERVACIONES: " & primeraLinea
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Hola gracias, hice el mismo ejemplo que me comentas, pero me salio error, asi es como me esta devolviendo los datos para la notificacion:  NOTIFICACIÓN DE INSTRUCCIÓN DE EMBARQUE:26596 - test1 - BOOKING:test1- OBSERVACIONES: ESTO ES PRUEBA DE TI" & vbLf & "SIGUE SIENDO PRUEBA DE TI"

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: me sale error, pero checare si hay una validación en este form ya que me sale esto : "La cadena especificada no tiene la forma necesaria para un asunto"